# Map Method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I was asked to define a function that would accept an array of strings, and use the map method to create another array with the trimmed strings.
My output trimmed the strings, however, it still said it was wrong. Can anyone tell me why?

```html
function cleanNames(){
    let cleanNames = [" Eric", "  Nanci", "   Luna"];
    let trimmedNames = cleanNames.map(function (elem) {
        console.log(elem.trim());
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, You can use arrow functions and also you have not returned anything from the map method which will be used to create a new array.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code itself, not a link to a painting of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the trimmed string in the map function.

```
array.map(function(ele){

    return ele.trim(); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it, but you're missing two `return` statements. Since this sounds like homework, I'll let you figure out where.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
const cleanNames = () => {
  /* you declare your variables */
  const names = [" Eric", " Nanci", "  Luna"];
  /* You map your array */
  names.map((el) => {
    /* You access each index and cut the blank spaces with the Trim () method */
    console.log(el.trim())
  })
}

/* You call your function */
cleanNames()
```

Comment: @EricPena If it worked for you, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

This will work to you. The problem is because you are not expecting an array and you are not returning the new array with the new array of trimmed strings

```js
function trimFunc(stringArray) {
  return stringArray.map(string => string.trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below solution:

```
function cleanNames(arr) {
 return arr.map(i => i.trim());
}

console.log(cleanNames(['njue', ' kamau', ' kimani','kalonzo']));
```